# I can't call a function in the parent from inside a python module

Tags: python, namespaces

My code looks like this:

```
def log(string):
    # this does stuff
def functionName(stuff):
    for module in moduleObjectList:
        returnvalue = module.main(args,stuff,self)
        if returnvalue:
            return returnvalue
```

In modules/mod_logging.py

```
def main(args,stuff,parent):
    parent.log("blah blah blah")
    return False
```

I tried something like

```
global log
```

without passing it the self argument, but it still didn't work

Everything is calling correctly, except I get a NameError. It says that "self" isn't defined. Why is that? And how do you think I should make my module system work?

Comment: Function definitions in python start `def`. And you haven't got `self` defined where you try to pass it from.

Comment: I recommend that you first go through a basic python tutorial and familiarize yourself with the language before asking questions on StackOverflow :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I meant def, my bad

Comment: @JoelCornett I know python, I just don't know why self isn't defined. I extensively researched how to call the parent in python, and there is no answer that works for this situation

Comment: @Niles I can only see what you type, not what you mean, and your computer is the same!

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is rather unclear (where does `args` come from?) but is it possible that you want:

```
 returnvalue = module.main(args, stuff, log)
```

and in `module`

```
def main(args, stuff, log):
     log("whatever")
```

You can pass functions as arguments, then call them.

If not, you will have to provide a lot more information about the structure of your module, what goes where and what for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this as a last resort. There will be a **lot** of functions to pass.

Comment: Then are you sure you're importing the right way around? I'm afraid it's hard to give a great answer here; we need more information to give you good advice.

Comment: I just sucked it up and passed all the functions and variables I needed, then used them with **kargs. Importing would have required loading the parent file through the text-based import multiple times per request. It works fine now, thanks.